# Extjs4 save all grid data in a table

Tags: extjs

I know how to get a value from a selected row of a grid, just like this:

```
var records = Ext.getCmp('My_Grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
var record  = records.length === 1 ? records[0] : null;
alert(record.get('name'));
```

But what I want is to get the `name` of all rows of the grid. To do it, I have used the method above, to write this functional function:

```
var MonTableau = new Array();
for (var j=0; j<=Ext.getCmp('My_Grid').getStore().getCount()-1; j++) {
Ext.getCmp('My_Grid').getView().select(j);
var records = Ext.getCmp('My_Grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
var record  = records.length === 1 ? records[0] : null;
MonTableau[j+1]=record.get('name');
                }
```

But it's not professional, I want more simple and professional method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExtJS store provides an [`each`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each) function which applies a passed `fn` for each record *cached* (already loaded) in the store:

```
var myStore = Ext.getCmp('My_Grid').getStore();
myStore.each(function(rec) {
    console.log(rec.get('name'));
});
```

P.S. I'm using `console.log();` rather than `alert();` as I think it's easier to read everything from the browser log.